# Why does 'I' change for nested loops in a different function?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I've been finding some weird behaviours in my code and finally tracked it down to what I considered impossible.
A variable "i" used in a for loop is changed within an enclosing for loop on another function.

In this case function a only logs 0 and function b 0-9. The behaviour I wanted was for both functions to log 0-9.

I solved the problem in my code changing the variable name 'i1' & 'i2'. But I'm guessing there is a more elegant solution.

```
function a() {

    for (i=0;i<10;i++) { // Changed to i1
    console.log('a',i);
    b() ; }

}

function b() {
    for (i=0;i<10;i++) { // Changed to i2
        console.log('b',i);
    }
}

a() ;
```

Comment: Thank you all for your answers.

Comment: Could you accept an answer you found useful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `let` when declaring your local variables. Otherwise, as others have mentioned, `i` becomes global.

```
function a() {

    for (let i=0;i<10;i++) {
    console.log('a', i);
    b(); }

}

function b() {
    for (let i=0;i<10;i++) {
        console.log('b', i);
    }
}

a();
```

Tip: It is generally better practice to [use `let` over `var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let). It will help you limit the scope of your local variables. In the example above, using `let` limits the scope of `i` to within the loop, whereas `var` would set the entire function as the scope (try using `var` and printing the value of `i` after the loop).

Answer (score 0):

You are adding i to the Global window object, this will behave as you expect:

```
function a() {

    for (var i=0;i<10;i++) { // Changed to i1
    console.log('a',i);
    b() ; }

}

function b() {
    for (var i=0;i<10;i++) { // Changed to i2
        console.log('b',i);
    }
}

a();
```

Place 'use strict'; at the top of every Javascript file and you will never have that kind of strangeness happen again. Place 'use strict' at the top of your Javascript now. You will see that there is an error at both i's because you are declaring them with `var` keyword.

When you started you declared i in your first for loop `(i=0;i<10;i++)` you put i in the global scope: `window.i`. Thus both for loops are using the same `window.i` variable.

The second for loop in function b does not declare a new `i` variable, the global i variable is used because it was created in function a.

Comment: "Place 'use strict'; at the top of every Javascript file" --- it's 2019 now, why not use modules

Comment: @zerkms wow really, for the OP to modules, do you realize where the OP is sandboxing?

Comment: @zerkms or did you just find an opportunity to be rude, users like are what gives SO  a bad rep amongst some circles, the haughty pretentious know it alls, meanwhile you give no care where the OP is in his studies of Javascript

Comment: First thing, I did not intend to be rude, sorry if it looked like that (and a protip: you don't need to attack people back, just in case if there is misunderstanding, like for someone else english is not the first language so they may not feel some notes). It was a genuine suggestion to use standards that are ~5~ 4 years old these days, not something from 00s.

Comment: And as soon as you started the game of who is the biggest pedant: "You are adding i to the Global window object" --- how do **YOU** know they run JS in an environment with a global _window_ object?

Answer (score 0):

There is a few issues. One is issue the variable `i` should be declared in the for loop:

```
for (i=0;i<10;i++)
```

should be changed to

```
for (let i=0;i<10;i++)
```

The other change to make is the `b` function should be called outside the loop. The full solution would be:

```
function a() {
    for (let i=0;i<10;i++) {
        console.log('a',i);
    }
    b();
}

function b() {
    for (let i=0;i<10;i++) {
        console.log('b',i);
    }
}

a();
```

Answer (score 0):

the way you are using **i** causes javascript to consider it as a global variable.  Other languages might have the **i** variable be local to the for loop's scope by default, but javascript doesn't work this way.  Javascript is designed so variables are global by default.  You can limit a variables scope to a function with **var**, such as:

```
function a() {

    for (var i=0;i<10;i++) {
        console.log('a',i);
    b() ; }

}
```

Please note that this scopes **i** to the *function*, *not* the for loop as you may want.  You can use the newer **let** keyword to define variables with more granular scoping (as of ES2015).  Here is an example of the **i** variable being scoped to the *for loop only* (not the function):

```
function a() {

    for (let i=0;i<10;i++) {
        console.log('a',i);
    b() ; }

}
```

Comment: "is designed as a scripting language so variables are all global by default" --- there is no connection between it being a scripting language and scoping rules.

Comment: Hmm.  Ok, I could be wrong.  It just seems like a thing scripting languages tend to do.  I'm going to look further into this and adjust accordingly.

Comment: Python is scripting and does not do that. php is scripting and does not do that.

Comment: K.  I've edited out the statement connecting scoping to scripting language status.